# Pinpointing and eliminating a segmentation fault

Tags: c

Through GDB I have determined that the segfault is occuring somewhere in this block of code.

```
readInfo(fd)

int fd;

 {
  char str[200];
  while(readInfo(fd,str))
   printf("%s\n",str);
 }
```

What this code is trying to accomplish is to read information sent to it by a server. I'm not quite sure what the problem is. Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: To be more specific:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0804864b in readInfo ()
```

Comment: I have a problem with a function named `a`. What is the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: What's readInfo()? My guess without knowing is that str isn't getting filled in correctly and printf() is running off the end of the buffer.

Comment: What happens if the server sends you more than 200 bytes?

Comment: I'm confused, the snippet shows a *really* old-style function def for `readInfo` which takes parameter `fd`.  But the while loop uses a call to `readInfo` with two params.  I suspect the problem involves this mismatch and you've disabled a number of compiler warnings to get something that compiles.

Comment: Is this actually an old-style C function like `void readInfo (int fd) {…}` that calls itself recursively with an additional parameter? I'm not even sure how that could possibly compile…

Comment: readInfo function should recieve the string,, readInfo(int fd, char str[]) { .... }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have three tips:

1. Compile the program with debugging symbols. That way you can see the actual code that you are crashing on, as well as print variable values even after the crash.
2. Write two functions - the non-recursive version and the recursive version. This isn't always necessary, but since you're adding a parameter, it is for you.
3. Somewhere in there you're going to actually have to write some code that reads from the file descriptor.